# RSS - This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below

Tags: rss, feed

i have a problem with my feed on wordpress that shows this message before the feed

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

https://www.rnbjunk.com/feed/

someone can let me know hot to resolve this and get back a result with a plain text feed like this

https://www.tpi.it/feed/

Thank you

Comment: I'm not seeing this issue on the provided urls.

Comment: the problem is still here.